# Alterações feitas em um registro são refletidas nos outros registros (Access + VBA)

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Criei um Form para reserva de Veículo onde tenho um campo onde o usuário deve inserir o destino da viagem. O usuário também pode precisar de mais de um destino, por isso criei um botão add_destino que faz sejam inseridas textbox no Form para cada destino adicional.

O problema é que ao inserir um Textbox no Registro 1 essa ação é refletida em todos os outros registros já cadastrados (Consegui apenas para "if Form_newrecord = true" para que as TextBox sejam retiradas). Então quando vou para qualquer outro registro e apago alguma Textbox com o botão del_destino, novamente, as Textbox dos outros registros somem junto, mesmo tendo conteúdo.

Como posso evitar esse problema.

Além disso, como posso salvar o estado do Form para que quando seja aberto de novo a Text box esteja lá caso tenha sido ativada?

Espero não ter sido muito confuso.

```
    Private Sub addPassageiro_Click()
' Botão que adiciona passageiros à requisição

If txtQtdPass < 19 Then
    cont = cont + 1
    txtQtdPass = cont
    ' checar se cont é par o ímpar
    If cont Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Me.Controls("passageiro" & cont).Top = Me.Controls("passageiro" & cont).Top + 200 * cont
        Me.Controls("passageiro" & cont + 1).Top = Me.Controls("passageiro" & cont + 1).Top + 200 * cont

        Me.Form.InsideHeight = Me.Form.InsideHeight + 400
        lblsaida.Top = lblsaida.Top + 400
        Saida.Top = Saida.Top + 400
        Destino.Top = Destino.Top + 400
        Destino1.Top = Destino1.Top + 400
        Destino2.Top = Destino2.Top + 400
        Destino3.Top = Destino3.Top + 400
        lblmoto.Top = lblmoto.Top + 400
        Motorista.Top = Motorista.Top + 400
        lblveiculo.Top = lblveiculo.Top + 400
        Veiculo.Top = Veiculo.Top + 400
        lblinfo.Top = lblinfo.Top + 400
        Infos.Top = Infos.Top + 400

    End If


Else
    MsgBox "Não é possível adicionar mais passageiros"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Ei Ookami, poderia me enviar o seu codigo para lhe ajudar melhor?

Comment: @ThalesFerraz, Adicione o código à pergunta.

Comment: Ei Ookami, está bem confuso porque no texto você fala de adicionar e apagar "destinos" e no código você tem apenas a opção de adicionar "passageiros". O problema não é nem ser diferente de destinos para passageiros porque isso dá para interpretar, mas é que pela sua descrição o problema ocorre ao apagar e o código apresentado é somente de adicionar. Poderia por gentileza adicionar o código completo?